# Insert into SQLITE Using single variable

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

What is the correct way to insert data into a single column in a table using a python variable?

I have tried

```
   crsr.execute("INSERT INTO PBI(Acceptance_Criteria) VALUES (?)",wi_criteria)
   connection.commit()
```

Gives Incorrect bindings error

```
crsr.execute(f"INSERT INTO PBI(Acceptance_Criteria) VALUES {wi_criteria})
connection.commit()
```

Gives Incomplete input

What is the correct format please? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be passing a tuple as the second parameter to `cursor.execute()`:

```py
crsr.execute("INSERT INTO PBI (Acceptance_Criteria) VALUES (?)", (wi_criteria,))
connection.commit()
```

Comment: I think I tried that. Let me check. Aah..I didn't place the comma after `wi_criteria`